# How to install package not in site-packages of virtualenv and put command in requirements.txt that will install this package from local dir?

Tags: python, django, pip, easy-install, django-oscar

I have some django packages like `django-oscar`. I need to install it with pip and then edit code & revise.

I'm tried to install it through `setup.py deploy` and to make `.egg-info`. Then I understand that pip doesn't have feature to install packages through `.egg-info`.

I also tried to install package from local directory using `-e /path/to/package`, but pip doesn't allow me install from  directory. It message me: `--editable=src/django-oscar-master/oscar/ should be formatted with svn+URL, git+URL, hg+URL or bzr+URL`

Then I'm tried to install through `pip install django-oscar --no-index --find-links=file://src/django-oscar-master/` and similar commands. It always message me: `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-oscar`

How to install package not in `site-packages` of virtualenv and put command in `requirements.txt` that will install this package from local dir?

Comment: This isn't really what pip was designed to do. You should post your version of django-oscar to github, then reference that in your pip requirements.txt

Comment: may be I can done it by other tools like `easy_install` or `setuptools`? Because I haven't chance to store it in external repository.

Comment: You might as well just include it in your project directory as you would a Django app you are making.

Comment: Yes, but in that case apps nested in django-oscar for some reason not installed. I don't know why, just migrations scripts don't running for  apps.

Comment: stormlifter you're answered on my question. problem solved. very big thanks. You can add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really what pip was designed to do. You should post your version of django-oscar to github, then reference that in your pip requirements.txt

Or if you don't want to have it hosted remote you might as well just include it in your project directory as you would a Django app you are making.